# ERROR: relation "public.TableName" does not exist PG

Tags: php, node.js, postgresql, pg

When hitting `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate` it does say ERROR: relation "public.Users" does not exist

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /*
      Add altering commands here.
      Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

      Example:
      return queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
    */
    return queryInterface.addColumn('Users', 'house_no', {type: Sequelize.STRING})
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /*
      Add reverting commands here.
      Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

      Example:
      return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
    */
  }
};
```

What we are missing can anyone suggest ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps missing double quotes?

Comment: Where missing double quotes ?

Comment: The table name with the upper case characters.

Comment: same issue with lower case as well